# Zero Padding a 3D Array

Tags: dask

I have a 3D array of data that I would like to zero pad symmetrically in the first two axes. I'm trying to use the dask array concatenate function: http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-stack.html but it can only handle one axis, whereas I need to pad in two dimensions.

```
import dask.array as da

data = da.random.random((20, 30, 4), chunks=(1,1,2))
padding = da.zeros((10, 10, 4)), chunks=(1,1,2))

res = da.concatenate((padding, data, padding), axis=0)
```

This doesn't work since axis would need two arguments to properly concatenate in two dimensions.

I am trying to replicate this from numpy:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random((20, 30, 4))
n_pad = 10
res = np.pad(data, ((n_pad, n_pad), (n_pad, n_pad), (0,0)), mode='constant', constant_values = 0)
```

Which returns the expected resulting shape of (40, 50, 4). 
The application for this is that I need to zero pad my experimental data for some FFTs, but the required zero paddings brings the array shape from (101, 101, 1024) to let's say (1024, 1024, 1024), which for complex values will be 16 Gb,  which is out of memory calculations. I have found this:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/out-of-core-fft/1.0 but unfortunately it only works on 1D arrays.

Comment: Perhaps you can call concatenate multiple times?

Comment: If I try to concatenate 3D arrays I get a Value Error: Block shapes do not align